# A "codeanywhere" sans serif font identification

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

[image]

I want to purchase it to use in a commercial logo.

Comment: Welcome! You get to be the guinea pig for our "Font Identification Guidelines" - please have a look and comment on them if anything isn't clear! Just wrote them: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/guidelines-for-font-identification-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks close to [Flexo Demi](http://www.myfonts.com/search/flexo+demi/fonts/), (use this site to identify your fonts)

[image]

Comment: Dangit Ilan, trying to promote getting the person asking to make a proper title. You're just too fast :(

Comment: ubuntu is also close, but free.  http://typecast.com/preview/google/Ubuntu